# Box-Shadow removes part of div background

Tags: html, css, containers

I'm having a problem where I need a box shadow of two divs to extend outside their container. This works fine, however when using the box shadow, it seems to remove a section from the right side of the 2 divs.

As seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ezuydakf/

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 30px 200px;
  background: blue;
  height: 300px;
}
.test1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: -200px 0 0 0 #eee;
}
.test2 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: -200px 0 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test1">TEST1</div>
  <div class="test2">TEST2</div>
</div>
```

The red and grey should keep going until the edge of the container, but as you can see the container is showing through (the blue part).

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve? A visual would help so much.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="test1">TEST1</div><br/><br/>
<div class="test2">TEST2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
margin: 30px 200px;
background: blue;
height: 300px;
width:550px;
}

.test1 {
width: 100%;
background: #eee;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #333;
margin:0;padding:0;
}

.test2 {
width: 100%;
background: red;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #333;
margin:0;padding:0;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Refer http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp for box-shadow property.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem I'm having. The JSFIDDLE I posted is almost exactly right except the divs background colours get cut off on the right side. All that needs to change is they need to fill the rest of the container horizontally. I still need the box-shadows to go outside the divs.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, try "box-shadow: -200px 0 0 red;" instead of "box-shadow: -200px 0 0 0 red;" for class test2 as you have mentioned.

Comment: @PavithraAshwath, this will have no impact at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Do you want some shadow in both sides...like this?**

```
.test1 {
    width: 100%;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: -200px 0 0 0 #eee,  200px 0 0 0 #eee;
}

.test2 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    box-shadow: -200px 0 0 0 red,  200px 0 0 0 red;
}
```